# how to get the scheduling statistics of threads in linux?

Tags: linux, multithreading

In Linux, we can use "cat /proc/processs-id/sched" to get the scheduling infomation, nr_switches，nr_voluntary_switches，nr_involuntary_switches tell us how many times has the process be scheduled. Is there any similar method that we can get a thread's scheduling times?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know what you mean by "scheduling times".  If you mean kernel/user run ticks then `/prox/xxx/stat` looks like it has some details about the runtimes.

Under linux, the threads of a process can be found in `/proc/xxx/task/yyy`.  Each directory corresponds to a thread process associated with the parent.

> **utime %lu**  Amount of time that this process has been scheduled in user mode, measured in clock ticks (divide by sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK).  This includes guest time, guest_time (time spent running a virtual CPU, see below), so that applications that are not aware of the guest time field do not lose that time  from their calculations.
>
> **stime %lu** Amount of time that this process has been scheduled in kernel mode, measured in clock ticks (divide by sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK).

I'd check the proc manpages for a list of the available files.

> man proc

Comment: thanks, but what i want to know is how many times has a thread been shceduled, not process.

Comment: Under linux, the threads of a process can be found in `/proc/xxx/task/yyy`.  Each directory corresponds to a thread process associated with the parent.